# Get property names of object

Tags: typescript

I want to get the property names of a simple Typescript object.

```
export class Simple {
    myProperty: string;
    otherProperty: string = "some text";
}

var s = new Simple();
Object.getOwnPropertyNames(s) --> ["otherProperty"]
for(var property in s) {console.log(property)} --> "otherProperty"
Object.keys(s) --> ["otherProperty"]
```

I don't understand why "myProperty" is not caught. How can i get the property names of the properties that are not initialized ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to remember that TypeScript is mostly syntactic sugar on top of JavaScript. Everything that does not have an immediate effect on JavaScript will not carry over when compiling your TypeScript code.

In this case, you have member declarations. The primary feature of this is to define which members an object may have. JavaScript itself does allow you to set arbitrary members on any object, so having member declarations on a TypeScript type restricts which members you have access to.

For your particular case, you declare two valid members on your class: `myProperty` and `otherProperty`. In addition, you also initialize `otherProperty` with a value.

Think about what happens in JavaScript land at this point: Member declarations do not exist, so all that’s left is the initialized member `otherProperty`. In particular, this is what your class declaration compiles to in JavaScript:

```
export class Simple {
    constructor() {
        this.otherProperty = "some text";
    }
}
```

As you can see, there is no `myProperty` because nothing is ever assigned to it. So for the JavaScript side, it does not exist (yet).

This means that at run-time (JavaScript is the run-time of TypeScript), the only property that exists an object of type `Simple` is `otherProperty` which is why that’s the only one you get when inspecting your object.

Comment: I understand, thank you very much for this clear explanation. But is there a "syntactic" method on Typescript that allows you to get the properties of an object ? Something kind of "static" like Simple.getProperties()

Comment: There isn’t, since none of this information is compiled to JavaScript. You could maybe write a pre-build step that analyzes the TypeScript code and then exposes the type information as some metadata separately. Not sure how you would begin with that though. On a somewhat related topic, take a look at [decorators](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html) which can also be compiled in a way that exposes the decorator metadata to JavaScript (at the bottom of the page).

Comment: Thank you ! I was looking for this kind of stuff, but was looking at "Attributes" (C# !) rather than "Decorators" ;)